# Turn String With Spaces and Characters Into URL-ready Address (like Wordpress, etc) Using PHP

Tags: php

I've built a custom CMS that does the usual things: post management, content management, contact management, etc.

In the post management section, I would like to extract the "Title" field and convert this into a URL-ready form.

Example: New post is created titled "3 Ways to Win in Real Estate & in Life". I want this to run through a PHP script that turns it into "3_ways_to_win_in_real_estate_&_in_life".

Anyone have a script for this, or would url_encode() do all of this for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make use of currently developed code that you can use within your own projects.

Kohana 3 framework has solution for you. Below you can find solution on the basis of [URL::title() method](http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/api/URL#title) from Kohana 3 framework:

```
function title($title, $separator = '-') {
    // Remove all characters that are not the separator, letters, numbers, or whitespace
    $title = preg_replace('![^' . preg_quote($separator) . '\pL\pN\s]+!u', '', strtolower($title));

    // Replace all separator characters and whitespace by a single separator
    $title = preg_replace('![' . preg_quote($separator) . '\s]+!u', $separator, $title);

    // Trim separators from the beginning and end
    return trim($title, $separator);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a dash of [str_replace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to turn the spaces into underscores, and a sprinkle of [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) to catch the rest.

Edit: I missed the [strtolower](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) part, but I think you had a handle on that.

This is of course just a basic way to go about it, if you want to exactly imitate the wordpress way of turning a text into a URL, have a look at that code, it's open and available for you to do so.

Answer (score 1):

```
function cleanURL($string)
{
    $url = str_replace("'", '', $string);
    $url = str_replace('%20', ' ', $url);
    $url = preg_replace('~[^\\pL0-9_]+~u', '-', $url); // substitutes anything but letters, numbers and '_' with separator
    $url = trim($url, "-");
    $url = iconv("utf-8", "us-ascii//TRANSLIT", $url);  // you may opt for your own custom character map for encoding.
    $url = strtolower($url);
    $url = preg_replace('~[^-a-z0-9_]+~', '', $url); // keep only letters, numbers, '_' and separator
    return $url;
}

// echo cleanURL("Shelly's%20Greatest%20Poem%20(2008)");  // shellys-greatest-poem-2008
```

from [here](http://www.phpsnaps.com/snaps/view/clean-url/).  You can write your own or possibly find one to replace things like `&` with `and`, and so on.

Also note that this function uses dashes, not underscores. The preferred way to create clean URLs is with dashes, not underscores.

Answer (score 1):

This is basic, but works.

```
  static public function slugify($text)
  {
    // replace all non letters or digits by -
    $text = preg_replace('/\W+/', '-', $text);

    // trim and lowercase
    $text = strtolower(trim($text, '-'));

    return $text;
  }
```

From here:
http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/05

Answer (score 1):

"Anyone have a script for this, or would url_encode() do all of this for me?"
Have you tried using `url_encode()` to do this for you? A quick test script would have revealed that much for you, or even using [functions-online.com's urlencode() tester](http://www.functions-online.com/urlencode.html).

```
$str = '3 Ways to Win in Real Estate & in Life';
echo urlencode( $str );
// 3+Ways+to+Win+in+Real+Estate+%26+in+Life
```

You could use a simple `preg_replace()` and simple replace anything which is not a letter or digit with either an underline or a dash.

```
echo preg_replace( '/[^\d\w]+/' , '_' , $str );
// 3_Ways_to_Win_in_Real_Estate_in_Life
echo preg_replace( '/[^\d\w]+/' , '-' , $str );
// 3-Ways-to-Win-in-Real-Estate-in-Life
```